# Number of Arithmetic Means inserted between 2 quantities

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $n$ Arithmetic Means are inserted between two quantities $a$ and $b$, then their sum is equal to what ?

What's the formula for these type of questions ? And can you please explain how it's derived ?

Answer (score 2):

let
$$a_0=a\,,a_1\,,\cdots,a_n\,,a_{n+1}=b$$
such that $a_{i+1}-a_i=d$
then
$$d=\frac{b-a}{n+1}$$
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+1}{{{a}_{i}}}=\frac{n+2}{2}\left( 2a+(n+1)d \right)=\frac{n+2}{2}\left( 2a+b-a \right)=\frac{n+2}{2}\left( a+b \right)$$
**Note**
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{a}_{i}}}=\frac{n+2}{2}\left( a+b \right)-(a+b)=\frac{n}{2}(a+b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}$ be the $n$ A.M.'s between $a$ and $b$. Then $a, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}, b$ are in A.P. Let $d$ be the common difference of the A.P.
Then, $t_{n+2}=b \Rightarrow a+(n+2-1) d=b \Rightarrow d=\left(\frac{b-a}{n+1}\right)$.
$\therefore \quad x_{1}=\left[a+\frac{(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right] ; x_{2}=\left[a+\frac{2(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right] ; \ldots ;$
$\quad x_{n}=\left[a+\frac{n(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right] .$
$\therefore$ Sum of $n$ arithmetic means between $a$ & $b$ $=x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+\ldots+x_{n}$
$=\left[a+\frac{(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right]+\left[a+\frac{2(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right]+\ldots+\left[a+\frac{n(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right]$
$=n a+(1+2+3+\ldots+n) \cdot\left(\frac{b-a}{n+1}\right)$
$=n a+\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \cdot \frac{(b-a)}{(n+1)}$
$=n \cdot\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$
$=n \times($ A.M . between $a$ and $b)$.