# Sum of all $n$ arithmetic means is equal to $n$ times single arithmetic mean.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

My teacher asked us to note a property which states that if there are two APs (Arithmetic Progression) such as $a, x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n, b$ and $a, y, b$, then $ny =  x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4+\dots+ x_n.$

I cannot visualize this, I mean how??? I understand that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n=ny$ where $y$ is some number, but I don't understand why would that number fit so gracefully between $a$ and $b$ such that $b - y = y - a?$

Thanks.

Comment: Draw a segment. What's the mean of the two points in the extremes? The middle. Now subdivide this segment in three. What's the mean of the three points? The middle, because the new point has not changed anything. Now subdivide it in four. What's the mean? The middle, because all points are symmetric respect to this point. That's the property. The middle in your case is $y$, and you obtain the mean of $x_i$ dividing by $n$ in the original expression.

Comment: thanks, idk why is this so hard for me to understand right now but ill keep your illustration in mind and think about it

Comment: $y=\frac{a+b}2=\frac{x_1+x_n}2=\frac{x_k+x_{n-k+1}}2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i=a+id\;$ and $\;b=a+(n+1)d$, where $d$ is the common difference of the first A.P. Observe,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\;x_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\; a+id=na+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}d=n\left(\frac{2a+(n+1)d}{2}\right)=n\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)=ny .$$

Comment: thanks :))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact the terms equidistant from the ends sum up to twice the arithmetic mean, AM.

Thus, the sum of all the arithmetic means is the product of the number of arithmetic means and the AM of the end terms.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{n}$
ARITHMETIC MEANS BETWEEN TWO GIVEN NUMBERS

Let $a$ and $b$ be two given numbers. Let $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}$ be the $n$ arithmetic means between $a$ and $b$. Then $a, x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}, b$ are in A.P. In this A.P., the first term is $a$, the last term is $b$ and the number of terms is $(n+2)$. Let $d$ be the common difference of the A.P. Then,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
b=a+(n+2-1) d \Rightarrow d=\left\{\frac{(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right\} \\
x_{1}=\left[a+\frac{(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right] ; x_{2}=\left[a+\frac{2(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right] \\
x_{n}=\left[a+\frac{n(b-a)}{(n+1)}\right] \quad n[48)=
\end{array}
$$
are the required arithmetic means between $a$ and $b$.

For the sum of $n$ arithmetic means, see this post [Number of Arithmetic Means inserted between 2 quantities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856182/number-of-arithmetic-means-inserted-between-2-quantities)